# Change font size on a CSS menu

Tags: html, css

this is my first ever CSS coding, and I have this CSS code that I took from a website to adapt it to what I want to do, however when I try to change the font size of the drop down menu it doesn't change.

Here's the CSS code:

```css
<!-- CSS menu -->
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #141414;
  text-align: center;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  border-bottom: 0px solid #0fa1e0;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 50px;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  background: #141414;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
  margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #0fa1e0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:first-child > a,
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  background: #070707;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #262626), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0fa1e0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
  font-size: 11px;
  filter: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #0a6d98;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
 <li class='active has-sub'><a href='techniques.html'><span>Techniques</span></a>
  <ul>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='attacks.html'><span>Attacks</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li class='has-sub'><a href='Aclosehanded.html'><span>Close-Handed</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='gyaku-tsuki.html'><span>Gyaku-Tsuki</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='oi-tsuki.html'><span>Oi-Tsuki</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='uraken.html'><span>Uraken</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li class='has-sub'><a href='Aopenhanded.html'><span>Open-Handed</span></a>
        <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='nukite.html'><span>Nukite</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='shotei-uchi.html'><span>Shotei-Uchi</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='shuto-uchi.html'><span>Shuto-Uchi</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='soto-uchi.html'><span>Soto-Uchi</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li class='has-sub'><a href='legs.html'><span>Leg</span></a>
        <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='mae-geri.html'><span>Mae-Geri</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='mawashi-geri.html'><span>Mawashi-Geri</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='ushio-geri.html'><span>Ushio-Geri</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='yoko-geri.html'><span>Yoko-Geri</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='defenses.html'><span>Deffenses</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li class='has-sub'><a href='Dclosehanded.html'><span>Close-Handed</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='age-uke.html'><span>Age-Uke</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='gedan-uke.html'><span>Gedan-Uke</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='uchi-uke.html'><span>Uchi-Uke</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='yoko-uchi-uke.html'><span>Yoko-Uchi-Uke</span></a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
      <li class='has-sub'><a href='Dopenhanded.html'><span>Open-Handed</span></a>
        <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='shuto-uke.html'><span>Shuto-Uke</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='teiso-uke.html'><span>Teisho-Uke</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li class='has-sub'><a href='defensebasics.html'><span>Deffense Basics</span></a>
        <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>1</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>2</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>3</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>4</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='katas.html'><span>Katas</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>1</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>2</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>3</span></a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='movements.html'><span>Movements</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li class='last'><a href='8directions.html'><span>8 Directions</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='okuri-ashi.html'><span>Okuri-Ashi</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='suri-ashi.html'><span>Suri-Ashi</span></a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='positions.html'><span>Positions</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li class='last'><a href='moto-dachi.html'><span>Moto-Dachi</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='neko-ashi-dachi.html'><span>Neko-Ashi-Dachi</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='shiko-dachi.html'><span>Shiko-Dachi</span></a></li>
      <li class='last'><a href='zenkutsu-dachi.html'><span>Zenkutsu-Dachi</span></a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class='active has-sub'><a href='competition.html'><span>Competition</span></a>
  <ul>
   <li class='last'><a href='Ckata.html'><span>Kata</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='kumite.html'><span>Kumite</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class='active has-sub'><a href='history.html'><span>History</span></a>
  <ul>
   <li class='last'><a href='evolution.html'><span>Evolution</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='origins.html'><span>Origins</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='present.html'><span>Present</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class='active has-sub'><a href='otherstyles.html'><span>Other Styles</span></a>
  <ul>
   <li class='last'><a href='goju-ryu.html'><span>Goju-Ryu</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='shoto-kam.html'><span>Shoto-Kan</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class='active has-sub'><a href='philosophy.html'><span>Philosophy</span></a>
  <ul>
   <li class='last'><a href='inthedojo.html'><span>In the dojo</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='levels.html'><span>Levels</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And here it is how it shows now:

[image]

I tried adding font-size: to some of the menus but nothing changed.
I have also looked at some other questions around here but I can't adapt my code to the solution they recommend.

Any ideas on how to make the font of the texts in the blue squares bigger?

Comment: can you post your html too please?

Comment: can u also show the html code?

Comment: yes sorry, I added it now

Comment: Now tell us *which* font size setting(s) you tried to change and how.

Comment: It looks like your font-size will be 12px, based on `#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 12px;
}`. Did you add that?

Comment: I tried changing that to a much bigger number but nothing changed :(

Comment: Please (1) share your code via a JSFiddle; and (2) Explain exactly what you WANT to happen that isn't happening. Exactly.

Comment: @cobberboy Rather use the internal Codesnippet tool than JSFiddle.

Comment: Your code is broken as it stands here - so I guess you missed some portions of the css and this might also be the place where to look for the font-size.

Comment: @Christoph Oops, My bad: I didn't notice the snippet tool. I do find the question a bit vague though.

Comment: Revisit your css code and remove all the unnecessary stuff bit by bit - border-radius prefixes, old webkit gradient notation, duplicate rules like your font-size and then improve selectors. Then most likely you end up with css you actually understand and are able to modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are changing or adding `font-size` settings and they are not taking effect, it's because your styles are being overridden by more specific selectors, you've changed the wrong selector, or there's an error in your CSS. Unless you [broke the internet](http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03103/paper-kardashian_3103452b.jpg). All I had to do was change these two: `#cssmenu > ul > li > a` and `#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a`.

**Update to address your edited question**
To change the font-size of the menu items in blue boxes, you change:

```
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
   font-size: 24px;
}
```

```css
/* The rest of this is for my embedded example */

@charset "utf-8";

<!-- CSS menu -->
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #141414;
  text-align: center;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  border-bottom: 0px solid #0fa1e0;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  background: #141414;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
  margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #0fa1e0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:first-child > a,
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  background: #070707;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #262626), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0fa1e0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
  font-size: 18px;
  filter: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #0a6d98;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='techniques.html'><span>Techniques</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='attacks.html'><span>Attacks</span></a>
                <ul>
                     <li class='has-sub'><a href='Aclosehanded.html'><span>Close-Handed</span></a>
                        <ul>
                           <li class='last'><a href='gyaku-tsuki.html'><span>Gyaku-Tsuki</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='oi-tsuki.html'><span>Oi-Tsuki</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='uraken.html'><span>Uraken</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li class='has-sub'><a href='Aopenhanded.html'><span>Open-Handed</span></a>
                          <ul>
                           <li class='last'><a href='nukite.html'><span>Nukite</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='shotei-uchi.html'><span>Shotei-Uchi</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='shuto-uchi.html'><span>Shuto-Uchi</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='soto-uchi.html'><span>Soto-Uchi</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li class='has-sub'><a href='legs.html'><span>Leg</span></a>
                          <ul>
                           <li class='last'><a href='mae-geri.html'><span>Mae-Geri</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='mawashi-geri.html'><span>Mawashi-Geri</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='ushio-geri.html'><span>Ushio-Geri</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='yoko-geri.html'><span>Yoko-Geri</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='defenses.html'><span>Deffenses</span></a>
                <ul>
                     <li class='has-sub'><a href='Dclosehanded.html'><span>Close-Handed</span></a>
                        <ul>
                           <li class='last'><a href='age-uke.html'><span>Age-Uke</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='gedan-uke.html'><span>Gedan-Uke</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='uchi-uke.html'><span>Uchi-Uke</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='yoko-uchi-uke.html'><span>Yoko-Uchi-Uke</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                     <li class='has-sub'><a href='Dopenhanded.html'><span>Open-Handed</span></a>
                          <ul>
                           <li class='last'><a href='shuto-uke.html'><span>Shuto-Uke</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='teiso-uke.html'><span>Teisho-Uke</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li class='has-sub'><a href='defensebasics.html'><span>Deffense Basics</span></a>
                          <ul>
                           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>1</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>2</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>3</span></a></li>
                           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>4</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='katas.html'><span>Katas</span></a>
                <ul>
                     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>1</span></a></li>
                     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>2</span></a></li>
                     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>3</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='movements.html'><span>Movements</span></a>
                <ul>
                     <li class='last'><a href='8directions.html'><span>8 Directions</span></a></li>
                     <li class='last'><a href='okuri-ashi.html'><span>Okuri-Ashi</span></a></li>
                     <li class='last'><a href='suri-ashi.html'><span>Suri-Ashi</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='positions.html'><span>Positions</span></a>
                <ul>
                     <li class='last'><a href='moto-dachi.html'><span>Moto-Dachi</span></a></li>
                     <li class='last'><a href='neko-ashi-dachi.html'><span>Neko-Ashi-Dachi</span></a></li>
                     <li class='last'><a href='shiko-dachi.html'><span>Shiko-Dachi</span></a></li>
                     <li class='last'><a href='zenkutsu-dachi.html'><span>Zenkutsu-Dachi</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='competition.html'><span>Competition</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li class='last'><a href='Ckata.html'><span>Kata</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='kumite.html'><span>Kumite</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='history.html'><span>History</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li class='last'><a href='evolution.html'><span>Evolution</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='origins.html'><span>Origins</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='present.html'><span>Present</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='otherstyles.html'><span>Other Styles</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li class='last'><a href='goju-ryu.html'><span>Goju-Ryu</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='shoto-kam.html'><span>Shoto-Kan</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='active has-sub'><a href='philosophy.html'><span>Philosophy</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li class='last'><a href='inthedojo.html'><span>In the dojo</span></a></li>
            <li class='last'><a href='levels.html'><span>Levels</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, but now the drop down menu starts at the left of the screen instead of undert the 'father' menu. If you run the code snipper you'll see what I mean. What else did you change?

Comment: I had problems making your snippets work at all, so I added `position: relative` to to `#cssmenu`. Leave all your other styles alone, and just change the `font-size` on the selector I mentioned. If it doesn't work, I'd look for errors.

Comment: @p.bosch Your entire code is messed up - if you run your snippet you will see that it is messed up even worse. I recommend starting with a blank css file. Than step analyse the css rules, understand what they do and then add them to your file. This will probably reduce the amount of css and (hopefully) make it work like you intended.

Comment: Yeah @Christoph, I know. I was only demonstrating the selector he wanted changed. I don't care about the rest -- it doesn't work as pasted in his question.

Comment: @Rodney I wasn't talking to you but rather p.bosch... Sorry for the ambiguity;-)

Comment: No harm done... see also my comments to his question ;-D